# Creating a child Process C# win32 API

Tags: c#, winapi, process, wmi

I am using the CreateProcess MSDN call() to manually launch an application and here's my code

```
void LaunchProg()
{
    STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
    si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
    si.lpDesktop = "testProg";

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

    var lpCurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(executablePath);
    CreateProcess("c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe", null, 
    IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, IntPtr.Zero, lpCurrentDirectory, ref si, ref pi);
}
```

This code works perfectly fine and launches the program in the specified desktop "testProg" but the issue is that when notepad.exe creates a child process which has a new window. This window is displayed in the Default desktop and not within the "testprog" desktop view (Active desktop view)

Not sure as to which parameter is not set correctly for all the child windows to be spawned within the same active desktop. I looked at the documentation and it is not clearer to me.

Update on an observation: The child process is not inherited from the application launched but its a child process of a system process running in the default desktop.

Any pointers? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [What idiot would hard-code the path to Notepad?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/01/28/9954432.aspx) (a rhetorical question)

Comment: ofcourse not. This is so that the problem statement is clear.

Comment: How did you persuade notepad to spawn processes? Or perhaps you are telling fibs.

Comment: Go to View and click on help. It spawns help.exe

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686744(v=vs.85).aspx) about threads and desktops, if a desktop is specified in the STARTUPINFO, that is used, otherwise the default desktop for the windows station to which the process is connected will be used. In your case, it seems likely that notepad is not marking the handle to the desktop inheritable, or it is doing a CreateProcess that doesn't inherit handles. Maybe you could attach a debugger and see what parameters the CreateProcess is being called with?