# WINAPI CreateProcess child process is not running

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process

I'm using the article in [msdn creating child process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) because it's pretty close to what I want to achieve.

The questions in [creating a child process c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497392/creating-a-child-process-c-sharp-win32-api), [redirection using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684568/i-o-redirection-from-child-process-using-pipes-winapi)
were helpful do find a few error on my approach but there are mostl likely more errors than what I was able to find.

I'm trying to create a connection between parent and child processes using pipes where they are able to write and read to each others StdOut. In my solution I created two console applications named ParentTalk and ChildTalk.

From what I was able to see the child process is not running the code I created for it so I might be creating the child process wrongly

Parent.cpp

```
      #include <windows.h> 
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE childInRead = NULL;
HANDLE childInWrite = NULL;
HANDLE childOutRead = NULL;
HANDLE childOutWrite = NULL;

HANDLE parentInRead = NULL;

#define BUFSIZE 4096

void CreateChildProcess() {
    TCHAR applicationName[] = TEXT("ChildTalk.exe");
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    BOOL success = FALSE;

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = childInRead;
    si.hStdOutput = childInRead;
    si.hStdInput = childOutWrite;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    success = CreateProcess(NULL, applicationName, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    if (!success) {
        printf("Error creating child process \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Child process successfuly created \n");
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Parent process running.... \n");

    DWORD dRead, dWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr;
    secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    printf("Creating first pipe \n");

    if (!CreatePipe(&parentInRead, &childInWrite, &secAttr, 0)) {
        printf("\n error creating first pipe \n");
    }
    printf("Creating second pipe \n");

    if (!CreatePipe(&childOutWrite, &childOutRead, &secAttr, 0)) {
        printf("\n error creating second pipe \n");
    }

    if (!SetHandleInformation(parentInRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        printf("\n parentInRead SetHandleInformation \n");
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(childInWrite, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        printf("\n childInWrite SetHandleInformation \n");
    }

    childOutRead = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    parentInRead = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    printf("\n Creating child process..... \n");
    CreateChildProcess();

    for (;;){
        printf("Inside for loop \n");
        bSuccess = ReadFile(parentInRead, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            printf("error reading \n");
            break;
        }

        bSuccess = WriteFile(childInWrite, chBuf,
                    dRead, &dWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            printf("error writing \n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ChildTalk.cpp

```
 #include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pch.h"

#define BUFSIZE 4096

int main()
{
    DWORD dRead, dWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    HANDLE stdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE stdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    printf("Child process running....");

    if (stdIn == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || stdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        ExitProcess(1);
    }

    for (;;) {
        success = ReadFile(stdIn, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dRead, NULL);
        if (!success || dRead == 0) break;

        success = WriteFile(stdOut, chBuf, dRead, &dWritten, NULL);
        if (!success) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT1: There's no errors while running the code, the program stays at

```
bSuccess = WriteFile(childStdOut, chBuf,
                        dRead, &dWritten, NULL);
            if (!bSuccess) {
                printf("error writing");
                break;
            }
```

because it's waiting for input but when I type anything it print the "error writing" message. The message that I added to the child code "Child process running...." isnt printed

EDIT2: Changed code because i think the Handles were incorrect now it's printing "Inside for loop" but still no child process. Do I need to launch the console application of the child process first?

Comment: What output do you get? Please [edit]  your question and put clarifications _there_

Comment: you from both sides first call `ReadFile` **before** ant `WriteFile`. because you youse **synchronous** files - you hung in call `ReadFile` from both side. you need or use asynchronous pipes (the best) or coordinate read/write operations. do it in strict order. also in case asyncronous pipes - yu not need create 2 pipe pairs (4 handles). enough create single pipe pair (2 handles only - 1 in parent and one in child) and use this pipe for both read and write

Comment: and what you want ? you must hung in both sides in `ReadFile` call

Comment: @RbMm what I'm trying to accomplish is to show at child's StdOut what was written on parent's StdIn and show at parent's StdOut what was written at child's StdIn. There's an error on child process code because im reading what is at child's StdIn and writing it on the child's StdOut

Comment: i look very superficially for your code and view that both (child and parent) begin from read request. at this point (because you use synchronous files) both side must hung (read not return until io not complete, io not complete until some data not will be written by write, write not called until read not return) or read return some error

Comment: but shouldn't a console open for the child process? And it should be printed "Child process running...." correct?

Comment: @KushQQ to open a new console for child process, you should use the flag `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`:   `CreateProcess(NULL, applicationName, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some errors in your code.

First,

`childOutRead = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 parentInRead = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);`

the 2 handle get from CreatePipe, have been reseted to stdhandle, and lost the pipe handle.

Second,

```
CreatePipe(&childOutWrite, &childOutRead, &secAttr, 0);
```

should be `CreatePipe(&childOutRead, &childOutWrite, &secAttr, 0)`

Third,

the handle in SetHandleInformation() is not correct.

Well, let's return your question.

For the hiding of child process, its stdin/stdout handle are seted to pipe handle, so you are not able see the console, but it does run in the background.
I did some change with your example(for simplicity, asynchrony is not used):

Parent.cpp

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE childInRead = NULL;
HANDLE W1 = NULL;
HANDLE W2 = NULL;
HANDLE R2 = NULL;

HANDLE R1 = NULL;

#define BUFSIZE 4096

void CreateChildProcess() {
    TCHAR applicationName[] = TEXT("ChildTalk.exe");
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    BOOL success = FALSE;

    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    si.hStdError = W1;
    si.hStdOutput = W1;
    si.hStdInput = R2;
    si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    success = CreateProcess(NULL, applicationName, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    if (!success) {
        printf("Error creating child process \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Child process successfuly created \n");
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Parent process running.... \n");

    DWORD dRead, dWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE] = "hello";
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr;
    secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    printf("Creating first pipe \n");

    if (!CreatePipe(&R1, &W1, &secAttr, 0)) {
        printf("\n error creating first pipe \n");
    }
    printf("Creating second pipe \n");

    if (!CreatePipe(&R2, &W2, &secAttr, 0)) {
        printf("\n error creating second pipe \n");
    }

    if (!SetHandleInformation(R1, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        printf("\n R1 SetHandleInformation \n");
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(W2, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0)) {
        printf("\n W1 SetHandleInformation \n");
    }

    printf("\n Creating child process..... \n");

    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hStdIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    CreateChildProcess();
    for (;;) {
        printf("Inside for loop \n");

        //1. read from stdin
        bSuccess = ReadFile(hStdIn, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            printf("error reading \n");
            break;
        }

        //2. write to Pipe2
        bSuccess = WriteFile(W2, chBuf, 100, &dWritten, NULL); 
        if (!bSuccess) {
            printf("error reading \n");
            break;
        }

        //3. read from Pipe1
        bSuccess = ReadFile(R1, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            printf("error reading \n");
            break;
        }

        //4. write to stdout
        bSuccess = WriteFile(hStdOut, chBuf, 100, &dWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) {
            printf("error reading \n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And Its logical process:
[image]

Comment: Right now I'm only able to use one of the pipes I need to comment the other one, i.e. I can either read from the Parent StdIn and write on the Child StdOut or the other way around but not both at the same time. Is it because I'm trying to read from both pipes? Or are the handles for the child's StdIn and StdOut incorrect

Comment: It doesn't matter that you write to both pipes at the same time. But if you read at the same time and no data in each pipe, the 2 processes will be stuck.This variable(`childInRead`) has only been initialized. So handles for the child's StdOut and StdError are always equal to `NULL` , You can compare my code with yours to see the differences that I haven't pointed out.

Comment: The only thing that doesn't suit your requirement is no able to display message in child process. Or You can use namepipe to communicate with child process.